# How to Return variable from loop in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, variables, return

i'm looping trough some csv files to get two specific column values from them to compare later on.

I'm storing those values in an array but when i return it, i get only the values from the first csv file and not from all.

```
def ls_values():
    for lsFile in listdir(ls_input_path):
        ls_lines = get_LS_data(ls_input_path + lsFile)

        checkValues_ls = []
        for ls_line in ls_lines:
            id_ls = ls_line['ID']
            ls = ls_line['ls']
            checkValues_ls.append({'id': id_ls, 'ls': ls})
        return checkValues_ls
```

How can i return the array when the loop is finished?

Thanks!

Comment: Your return statement is inside your loop so it's going to return at the end of the first iteration.  Try moving your return back a level.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a list comprehension to make it easy:

```
def ls_values():
    return [
        {k.lower(): ls_line[k] for k in ('ID', 'ls')}
        for lsFile in listdir(ls_input_path)
        for ls_line in get_LS_data(ls_input_path + lsFile)
    ]
```

but the way to fix your original code would be to move the list initialization and the return to happen outside the loop (before and after, respectively):

```
def ls_values():
    checkValues_ls = []
    for lsFile in listdir(ls_input_path):
        ls_lines = get_LS_data(ls_input_path + lsFile)
        for ls_line in ls_lines:
            id_ls = ls_line['ID']
            ls = ls_line['ls']
            checkValues_ls.append({'id': id_ls, 'ls': ls})
    return checkValues_ls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ls_values():
    checkValues_ls = [] # Move this so it's not reset for every item
    for lsFile in listdir(ls_input_path):
        ls_lines = get_LS_data(ls_input_path + lsFile)

        for ls_line in ls_lines:
            id_ls = ls_line['ID']
            ls = ls_line['ls']
            checkValues_ls.append({'id': id_ls, 'ls': ls})
    return checkValues_ls # Return it at the end!
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your program is ok but you do not getting the expected return value. you only getting the first csv file data because you return in nested `loop`.
all you could do is just put the `return checkValues_ls` out side of `for loop`

```
def ls_values():
    checkValues_ls = []
    for lsFile in listdir(ls_input_path):
        ls_lines = get_LS_data(ls_input_path + lsFile)

        for ls_line in ls_lines:
            id_ls = ls_line['ID']
            ls = ls_line['ls']
            checkValues_ls.append({'id': id_ls, 'ls': ls})
    return checkValues_ls
```

hoping this will work in your case